# Transmission daemon: permission denied even if debian-transmission has root group

Tags: chmod, transmission

I've got something really strange. Transmission-daemon keeps telling me

> "Permission denied /home/transmission/downloads/.." (.. = name of torrent folder and files)

I created this folder transmission:

```
sudo mkdir /home/transmission
```

After this I've created folders inside:

```
sudo mkdir /home/transmission/incomplete
sudo mkdir /home/transmission/downloads
```

Give permission first just by making these folders from `debian-transmission`:

```
sudo chgrp -R debian-transmission:debian-transmission /home/transmission
```

Added myself to this group:

```
sudo usermod -a -G debian-transmission kurt
```

But still no access I could edit and add files to the downloads folder so I've added my group `kurt` to `debian-transmission`.

```
sudo usermod -a -G kurt debian-transmission
```

Permission denied.. hmmm. Okay then `chmod` this folder to 777.

```
sudo chmod 777 -R /home/transmission
```

Permission denied.. last thing I could do:

```
sudo usermod -a -G root debian-transmission
```

But nothing helps. I know this is not a good way. But I just wanted to test if this would work. I've restarted transmission service after every permission change just to be sure. Some extra information:

```
ps aux | grep transmission
output:
117      17319  0.4  0.4 397624 10196 ?        Ssl  18:33   0:05 /usr/bin/transmission-daemon -f --config-dir /var/lib/transmission-daemon/info
kurt     17767  0.0  0.0  13580   900 pts/0    S+   18:52   0:00 grep --color=auto transmission

ps -ef | grep transmission
117      17319     1  0 18:33 ?        00:00:05 /usr/bin/transmission-daemon -f --config-dir /var/lib/transmission-daemon/info
kurt     17827 17229  0 18:53 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto transmission

groups debian-transmission
debian-transmission root kurt

groups kurt
kurt adm cdrom sudo dip plugdev lpadmin sambashare debian-transmission
```

Anyone that has a good solution for my problem?

Comment: can you try the same thing with `sudo su`? `sudo` and `su` has some major differences.

Comment: Added sudo as group of debian-transmission. But nothing group su doesnt exist (restarted transmission after changing the permissions).

sudo service transmission-daemon restart

Comment: See also: [How to change the default permissions of files created by transmission-daemon?](http://askubuntu.com/q/157455)

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
mkdir /your_path/progress
mkdir /your_path/completed
sudo usermod -a -G debian-transmission your_user
chgrp debian-transmission /your_path/progress
chgrp debian-transmission /your_path/completed
chmod 770 /your_path/progress
chmod 770 /your_path/completed
sudo service transmission-daemon stop
sudo adduser your_user debian-transmission
sudo nano /etc/init.d/transmission-daemon
sudo chown your_user -R /var/lib/transmission-daemon/info/
sudo chown your_user -R /your_path/progress
sudo chown your_user -R /your_path/completed
sudo chown your_user -R /etc/transmission-daemon/settings.json
```

And change in the file:
    sudo nano /etc/transmission-daemon/settings.json

```
"rpc-whitelist": "127.0.0.1" > "rpc-whitelist": "*.*.*.*",
"rpc-password": "password" > "rpc-password": "your_password",
"download-dir": "/var/lib/transmission-daemon/downloads" > "download-dir": "/your_path/completed"
"incomplete-dir": "/var/lib/transmission-daemon/downloads" > "incomplete-dir": "/your_path/progress"
```

Just restart the daemon:

```
service transmission-daemon start
```

Comment: Worked for me, with the following variations: commit chomps and the last 4 chowns.

Comment: I get the following error when I start the daemon after following the above procedure: Job for transmission-daemon.service failed because the control process exited with error code.

Answer (score 1):

After hours of trial and error........this is what I did:

1.- edit /etc/init.d/transmission-daemon and set the "USER" variable to "root" to solve the folder permission issues

2.- edit /etc/default/transmission-daemon and set "CONFIG_DIR" variable to "/etc/transmission-daemon/" because I don't like having the config file in /var

Comment: Setting the user to "root" may solve the problem but is never a good a idea

Answer (score 1):

Had this happen to me.

Basically you need directory listing rights throughout the path to your storage. I just added r+x to others (chmod o+rx /partial/path).